# Playsound not playing sound

Tags: c++, error-correction, playsound

Here is what I tried

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" )
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PlaySound(L"C:\Users\Lol\Downloads\Music\Undertale OST - Hotel Extended.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me an error:

> incomplete universal character name \U|

Also before that it says:

> ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]|

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

> incomplete universal character name \U|

In character and string literals, certain [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) have special meaning to the compiler:

[image: escape sequences]

Your string literal contains 2 instances of the `\U` escape sequence, however there are no numeric values following the `\U` to make up the digits of valid Unicode codepoints, hence the compiler error.

To use actual `\` characters in your string literal, you need to escape them as `\\`, eg:

`L"C:\\Users\\Lol\\Downloads\\Music\\Undertale OST - Hotel Extended.wav"`

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), which uses a slightly different syntax that does not require you to escape characters manually:

`LR"(C:\Users\Lol\Downloads\Music\Undertale OST - Hotel Extended.wav)"`

> ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]|

How you link to `.lib` files is very toolchain-specific.  Your compiler (you did not say which one you are using) is telling you that it does not support the `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` directive.  So, you will have to link to `Winmm.lib` in another way that is more appropriate for your particular toolchain's linker.  Read the documentation for your toolchain.

Comment: I am a begginer at coding. I use CodeBlocks, and I found the code on another question in this site. Do you perhaps know how i can fix the pragma problem in CodeBlocks?

Comment: @LuckyFire see [Using libraries with Code::Blocks](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/), and also see [#pragma comment](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=7238.0) in the [Code::Blocks](http://forums.codeblocks.org) forum